# How can I extract multiple occurrences of dict from a string?

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I'm trying to extract multiple occurrences of python dict from a string. Currently I'm using regex which is failing as it also matches the data in between the dict. I also used the non-greedy regex `({.+?})` but it messes up the nested dictionaries and consider them as different occurrences.

Example string:

```
mystring = '(2017-05-29, { "mydict": [{ "hello": "world"}, {"hello2":"world2"}]};;/url/string, {"dict2":{"world":"hello"}}'
```

Code:

```
>>>import re
>>>match_data = re.compile('({.+})')
>>>match_data.findall(mystring.strip())
['{ "mydict": [{ "hello": "world"}, {"hello2":"world2"}]};;/url/string, {"dict2":{"world":"hello"}}']
```

Expected output:

```
['{ "mydict": [{ "hello": "world"}, {"hello2":"world2"}]}', '{"dict2":{"world":"hello"}}']
```

Comment: I think you'll need to write a parser for python dictionaries.

Comment: try this `re.findall(r'{.+?}', mystring))`, it won't give what you are excepting exactly, but you can parse the data easily.

Comment: is ";;/url/string" data always come at same place ?? like in between two dict??

Comment: @DexJ It can be anything, otherwise I would have just used `split()`. Also there can be other strings as well.

Comment: @Arun I already mentioned that in the description, the non-greedy regex will mess up the nested dict.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is probably too simplistic for this problem. However, one possible solution is to match the paratheses:

```
s = '{ "mydict": [{ "hello": "wo}}rld"}, {"hello2":"world2"}]};;/url/string, {"dict2":{"world":"hello"}}'


number_of_parthesis = 0
start_index = -1
in_quotes = False

for i,c in enumerate(s):
    if c in ["\'", "\""]:
        if in_quotes:
            in_quotes = False
        else:
            in_quotes = True
    if in_quotes:
        continue
    if c == "{":
        number_of_parthesis += 1
        if start_index == -1:
            start_index = i
    if c == "}":
        number_of_parthesis -= 1
        if number_of_parthesis == 0:
            print(s[start_index:i+1])
            start_index = -1
```

Which results in:

```
{ "mydict": [{ "hello": "wo}}rld"}, {"hello2":"world2"}]}
{"dict2":{"world":"hello"}}
```